# Comparison between two real valued functioons

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider two real valued functions: $f: \mathbb{Z}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{Z}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the sets of nonnegative integers and real numbers, respectively. Suppose we have $f(k) < g(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Can I claim that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(k) \leq g(k) - \epsilon$?

Some thoughts: I think this claim can be proved by using contradiction, but I have no idea how to prove in a rigorous way.

Comment: simply false, take $f(k)=-1/k$, $g(k)=0$

Comment: @Giulio R If the inequality condition also holds when $k = \infty$, in other words, $f(k) < g(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \cup \{\infty \}$, do we have such a claim?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Define $g(n) = 1$ and $f(n) =1-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: What about $f(k) < g(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \cup \{+\infty \}$?

Comment: You still can define $g(\infty) = 1$ ans $f(\infty)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: But if you require $f,g$ to be continous(where $\mathbb Z_{+} \cap \{\infty\}$ is the one point compactification of $\mathbb Z_{+}$ than you can prove the claim